# Etat HTTP 500 - Unable to find method [isDelaiAvis] with [0] parameters

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I'm getting the error:Etat HTTP 500 - Unable to find method [isDelaiAvis] with [0] parameters in my web application due to the EL expression in my XHTML file.

XHTML file

```
 <p:dialog  closable="false" modal="true" onShow="ovBodyHidden();" onHide="ovBodyHidden();" widgetVar="dlg2" visible="true" rendered="#{sessionBean.isDelaiAvis()}" >

   <img alt="Avis" src="ressources/Avis.PNG" />
    <h:form id="fCOV" > 
    <p:commandButton value="OK"  oncomplete="PF('dlg2').hide();" style="width:100%; height:30px;"/>
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

And in my bean i define the method:

```
public boolean isDelaiAvis() throws ParseException{
    
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date_avis = dateFormat.parse("2020-08-01");
    
    Date aujourd =dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    
    
    if(date_avis.compareTo(aujourd)>0) {
        
        return true;}
        else {
            
            return false;
            
        }
        
    }
```

Apparently my method is not recognized. Any idea how can i get over that problem? I'm using java 6.

Comment: try `h:outputText  value="Hello world" rendered="#{sessionBean.isDelaiAvis()}"` insread ofbthebhtml posted. Does it work? And if you just put `return true` in the method?

Comment: Or what if you remove the () in the EL

Comment: I tried your code and it works, Primefaces version? When you debug your code the method isn't called or do you have another problem?

Comment: @WoAiNii i change the name of the method to test() as suggested by Kukultje and it worked!! I don't know what is the problem with the name isDelaiAvis()